# Mod_Rewrite Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I know alot people have post about this error , however i still unable to solve it.So that is the reason why i start a new post with it.

As stated in the title , i encounter a redirect loop when accessing my pages in the website.

Here is my rewrite config.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /test/$1 [R]
```

So , how do I solve this redirect error?

```
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345204 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] applying pattern '(.*)$' to uri '/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test/ /store.do', referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345213 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] RewriteCond: input='http://example.com/test/store.do' pattern='^http://example\\.com/test/store\\.do' [NC] => matched, referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345218 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] rewrite '/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//whatshot_v3/hahah/store.do' -> '/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//store.do', referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345233 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] explicitly forcing redirect with http://example.com/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test/ /store.do, referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345239 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] escaping http://example.com/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//store.do for redirect, referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
[Fri May 16 12:18:20.345245 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 29462:tid 1193511232] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 172.16.28.96:60187] 172.16.28.96 - - [example.com/sid#1e84d1c0][rid#1e954910/initial] redirect to http://example.com/test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//test//store/store.do [REDIRECT/302], referer: http://example.com/test/store.do
```

Here is my log file.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the redirect that you have configured?

Comment: Well , I am doing reverse proxy. So i have a webpage like http://example.com/test/store.do by using proxypass. However , when i access any pages in that website , it will go to http://example.com/store/store.do. What i am trying to do here is to add the /test path for all the pages in that website.Or else i will get 404 error.

Comment: So, that `RewriteRule` is intended to proxy?  Is that correct?

Comment: yup. Its for proxy.

Comment: There's no remote host in that rule - what are you trying to proxy to?

Comment: I use proxypass for proxy..Not using mod_rewrite for proxy.

Comment: Ok, then we're back to "What are you trying to accomplish with the redirect that you have configured?"

Comment: First i use passproxy to RP to my website on another server.So like the example i given , i type example.com/test will lead to example.com/test/store.do. Now in that website has alot of pages , the problem is that everything(images,css,links) must from example.com/test/.However , the problem is that all the subpages are coming from example.com/ . thus causes 404 error. The rewriterule for this whole thing is to add to /test path infront of all the subpages. For an example , example.com/test/smth.do. Without the /test path , it will lead 404 error.

Comment: Thus , i try my rewriterule that i have shown , it create a loop (20times) , thus creating the err_too_many_redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, the best solution is probably to change the references to the other resources to include the `/test/` instead of hacking around it in mod_rewrite.

But, this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do [NC]
RewriteRule ^/test - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com/test/store\.do [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

Note that it's not redirecting since there's no reason to cause the client to send an extra request for each one of the resources, though that should still work.

Comment: still the same..still have the loop.
this is the log.

 prefixed with document_root to /usr/local/apache2/htdocs 
 go-ahead with /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

got this log now.

Comment: ok...i added the R flag, now it working already. Thanks alot. But can you explain RewriteRule ^/test - [L] . what this means?

Comment: @ku1918 It's making the following rule (which was causing the loop when applied to URLs under `/test`) not apply to URLs under `/test`.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to debug RewriteRules, the best thing to do is to turn on the rewrite log and crank up the rewriteloglevel. This will display the incoming request, and the pass/fail for each rule, as well as what it does with the request when it matches a rule.

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Remember to disable this once you've finished, as it does cause a performance hit, especially at 3 and above.

Comment: Yeah..i did that...just keep saying redirect 302 ..then all the loop path.

Comment: You should be able to see what rewrite rule is matching and what its rewriting it to that is causing the looping in the logs.